# converting canvas data to image canvas.toDataurl doesn't work in IE9

Tags: html, canvas

I have a canvas element with a drawing in it, and I want to create a button that when clicked on, it will save the image as a png file. So it should open up the save, open, close dialog box...

I do it using this code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
window.open(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
```

But when I test it out in IE9, a new window opens up saying "the web page cannot be displayed" and the url of it is:

data:image/png;base64,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

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Because they never implemented it. A bug was filed, and the IE team closed it as "by design" because they considered it a feature request.

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/587136/supporting-data-uris-for-all-resources